# Port 8080 failing & startup.sh cannot be found when deploying Sails app to Azure

Tags: javascript, azure, sails.js

I've followed all the provided MS tutorials but still cannot get my sails app to run on Azure. I get the following log error. Can anyone help as to why these errors are happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is the official Azure deployment strategy for Sails.
https://github.com/mikermcneil/sails-deploy-azure

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved my question. The error was created by an incorrect Redis URL. If you are using Redis ensure to add the Azure service Azure Cache for Redis and use the provided URL eg. redis://[your host name].redis.cache.windows.net:6380